# Aggregate Function Query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I want to Find out details of the proposals that have been assessed with the highest amount of grant approved.
There is some problem with the query, This is the error message.
You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Title' as an aggregate function in ms access.

```
SELECT Proposal.ProposalID,  Proposal.Title,  Proposal.RequestedAmmount, Researcher.Name, MAX(Proposal.RequestedAmmount)
FROM Researcher, Proposal
WHERE Researcher.ResearcherID=Proposal.ResearcherIDSub
GROUP BY  Proposal.ProposalID ;
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider providing [DDLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) together with some sample data and the desired result set

Answer (score 2):

In `GROUP BY` query  you need to group all paramters which are not inside function. So in your case `Proposal.Title,  Proposal.RequestedAmmount, Researcher.Name` also needs to be grouped.

You will need to re-look in your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` statement. See if you really need fields -  `Proposal.Title`,  `Proposal.RequestedAmmount`, `Researcher.Name`.
If you need them, than you need to group them too.

Comment: I have tried it, but its not returning the all the records in the TABLE. :(
But i want Max RequestedAmmount

Comment: `GROUP BY Proposal.ProposalID,  Proposal.Title,  Proposal.RequestedAmmount, Researcher.Name` should give all the records. If not, then you need to add additional column in SELECT and GROUP BY which you know will give all records after grouping.

Comment: Other option is to do a inner `SELECT` query to get all records.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has two problems:

- syntactically the group by must list *all* non-aggregate columns
- it's an *inner* join - meaning that there must exist proposals for the researcher to be returned; researchers without proposals will be excluded instead of having a NULL in the MAX() column

To address these points, change your query to

- `GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4` (the SQL standard allows group by columns to be referenced by both expression and column position - I find position to be clearer, easier and terser)
- Use an *outer* join by employing the more modern JOIN syntax with the LEFT option

As follows:

```
SELECT
    Proposal.ProposalID,
    Proposal.Title,
    Proposal.RequestedAmmount,
    Researcher.Name,
    MAX(Proposal.RequestedAmmount)
FROM Researcher
LEFT JOIN Proposal ON Researcher.ResearcherID=Proposal.ResearcherIDSub
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
```